# Как сделать проверку SWITCH в цикле в выводе (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, массивы, json, циклы

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "https://sait.com",
    data: "UserKey[auth_key]=" + localStorage.getItem("auth_key"),
    success: function (msg) {

      var tran = JSON.parse(msg)
      length = function(obj) {

        var size = 0;
        $.each(tran, function(i, elem) { size++; });
        return size;
      };

      var transactions = tran["transactions"];

      /*function (type) {
      switch(type){
        case 15: return "Пополнение баланса";break;
        case 16: return "Снятие баланса"; break;
      }}*/


      for(i=0;i<=length(tran);i++)
        $(".trans").append("<ul><li class=\"item-content\"><div class=\"item-inner\"><div class=\"item-title-row\"><div class=\"item-title\">"
          + transactions[i]['type'] + "</div><div class=\"item-after\" style=\"white-space:normal;width:90px;\">"
          + transactions[i]['created_at'] + "</div></div><div class=\"item-subtitle\">"
          + transactions[i]['value'] + "</div></div></li></ul>");
    },


    error: function () {
      swal("Поключение не удалось", "Проверьте Интернет-соединение и повторите попытку", "error");
    }
  });
});
```

Вывод историй транзакции работает, но там где type, выводит код действия, 
а надо сделать для каждого кода свой текст.
Например: 15 - это "С вашего счета снято" , 17 - это "На ваш счет начислено".
Я там закомментил `switch` c `case`(примерно накидал).
Не могу правильно засунуть в вывод, чтобы выводило текстом, а не числом.
Как правильно реализовать такую проверку в цикле для массива?

Answer (score 0):

Постановка задачи не верна. В данном случае лучше создать массив с вариантами типов транзакций и просто подставлять их при выводе.

```
<script>
  var type_of_transaction =[];
  type_of_transaction[15] = 'Income';
  type_of_transaction[16] = 'Out';

  var transaction = [];
  transaction[0] = '15';

  alert(type_of_transaction[transaction[0]]);

</script>
```